# java.io.IOException with gradle

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle 2.7 as a build tool on a linux amd64 m/c. When I try to do build using gradle I get java IO Exception.

> gradle --info

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
```

The stacktrace result is as follow:-

> gradle --stacktrace

```
    org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:67)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:36)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:40)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getIdle(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:123)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:122)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:80)
        ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It reads like gradle tried to create a new file, but could not. The path is not specified in the log.

Try to create a file in your project directory on command line as the user gradle runs as and fix permissions if necessary.